# Locked users' content fully blocked and unable to unlock

Tags: users

Just ran into an issue where one of my users was locked out due to too many login attempts (or at least it seems that way).

This caused all sorts of havoc in my site:

- The content that was created by that user was not accessible by
  others.
- The front end broke (though I guess I should've set an "if no
  user rule")
- The user couldn't be found in the users list.

In order to fix this I had to go into the database and change the locked status from 1 to 0.

- Has anyone else experienced this?
- Is there a better way of handling it? (while keeping the limit of attempts).
- Craft Team, can this be modified to cause less trouble? e.g.: lock the users but not their content; make the user unlockable from within the CP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely running into a bug that was fixed in [2.3.2636](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2636) where a locked user could cause all sorts of havoc on the CP.

If your version/build is before that, update to the latest and you shouldn't see it again.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, I'm behind on my updates due to some troubles I'd ran on my development server. Thanks!